# Issue while creating a CentOS 7 KVM guest

Tags: linux, kvm, centos7

I am trying to create a CentOS 7 KVM guest using virt-install executing the following command

```
# virt-install -n centos7 -r 2048  --vcpus=1 --os-type linux --os-variant=rhel7 --network bridge=br0 --nographics --location='http://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/' --extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial' --disk path=/mnt/sdb/kvms/images/centos7.img,size=12 --hvm
```

Execution fails showing the following message

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
dracut-initqueue[545]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
dracut-initqueue[545]: Warning: Could not boot.
dracut-initqueue[545]: Warning: /dev/root does not exist
Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...
Warning: /dev/root does not exist
Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"
Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.
dracut:/#
```

My server is Centos 6.5. I don't have any problem while creating either centos 5.X or centos 6.X KVM guests. I only face the problem while creating centos 7 guests. 
Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it tries to use the host's IP address. 
A solution that I found is to use a kickstart file in order to do the installation. 
I have written a blog post about it https://dimokaragiannis.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/issue-while-creating-a-centsos-7-kvm-guest/